# No funciona correctamente el código Jquery

Tags: jquery

Tengo tres checkbox que representan los costos de distintos trabajos y un input donde ingresar el pago (por defecto tiene un monto de 200). La idea es que al seleccionar alguno de los pagos, se compare el costo del trabajo y el monto del pago, y según corresponda mostrar por consola, si sobra dinero del pago realizado o si el trabajo queda con un pago incompleto.

Si con un pago de 200 (valor por defecto), selecciono el trabajo 1 cuyo costo es de 120, veo por consola lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual es correcto.

Si con el mismo pago de 200, selecciono el trabajo 3 cuyo costo es de 5000, veo por consola lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual también es correcto.

Pero (y aquí el problema) cuando selecciono el trabajo 2 cuyo costo es de 1000, veo por consola lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual es incorrecto. Ya que debería aparecer que restan pagar 800

Copio el código correspondiente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#trabajos_cliente').on('change','.imputacion', function(){

                if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    let trabajo = $(this).val();
                    let pago = $(this).parent().siblings('#pagos_cliente').children('#pago').val();

                    let faltan = trabajo - pago;
                    let sobran = pago - trabajo;


                    console.log("Costo del trabajo " + trabajo);
                    console.log("Monto del pago " + pago);

                    if(trabajo > pago){
                        console.log("Restan pagar del trabajo " + faltan);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Sobran del pago " + sobran);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="trabajos_cliente">
        <input class="imputacion" value="120.00" type="checkbox">Trabajo 1 - Precio: 120.00<br>
        <input class="imputacion" value="1000.00" type="checkbox">Trabajo 2 - Precio: 1000.00<br>
        <input class="imputacion" value="5000.00" type="checkbox">Trabajo 3 - Precio: 5000.00<br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="pagos_cliente">Pago para imputar : <input id="pago" value="200"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Especifica que los valores de trabajo y pago son float y así se soluciona el problema, por ejemplo:
                    let trabajo = parseFloat($(this).val());
                    let pago = parseFloat($(this).parent().siblings('#pagos_cliente').children('#pago').val());

Comment: Gracias track3r !!, si bien la respuesta que me dieron de ponerle Number funciona, creo que la tuya es mas correcta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu variables `trabajo` y `pago` son del tipo `string` por eso la comparación `trabajo > pago` falla. Debes transformarlos en `Number`

```
let trabajo = Number($(this).val());
let pago = Number( $(this).parent().siblings('#pagos_cliente').children('#pago').val());
```

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#trabajos_cliente').on('change','.imputacion', function(){

                if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
                    let trabajo = Number($(this).val());
                    let pago = Number( $(this).parent().siblings('#pagos_cliente').children('#pago').val());

                    let faltan = trabajo - pago;
                    let sobran = pago - trabajo;


                    console.log("Costo del trabajo " + trabajo);
                    console.log("Monto del pago " + pago);

                    if(trabajo > pago){
                        console.log("Restan pagar del trabajo " + faltan);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Sobran del pago " + sobran);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="trabajos_cliente">
        <input class="imputacion" value="120.00" type="checkbox">Trabajo 1 - Precio: 120.00<br>
        <input class="imputacion" value="1000.00" type="checkbox">Trabajo 2 - Precio: 1000.00<br>
        <input class="imputacion" value="5000.00" type="checkbox">Trabajo 3 - Precio: 5000.00<br>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div id="pagos_cliente">Pago para imputar : <input id="pago" value="200"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias!, ese era el problema